# script to join 2 separate text files and also add specified text

Tags: linux, bash, join, text

hi there i want to creat a bash script that does the following:

i have 2 texts files one is adf.ly links and the other Recipie names

i want to creat a batch scrript that takes each line from each text file and do the following

```
<li><a href="**TEXT FILE 1 ADFLY URL line 1** ">**Recipie name line 1 of txt file**</a></li>

<li><a href="**TEXT FILE 1 ADFLY URL line 2** ">**Recipie name line 2 of txt file**</a></li>
```

ect ect and save all the results to another text file called LINKS.txt

someone please help or point me in direction of linux bash script

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner will do the job:

```
 awk 'BEGIN{l="<li><a href=\"%s\">%s</a></li>\n"}NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{printf l, a[FNR],$0}' file1 file2
```

more clear version (same script):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{l="<li><a href=\"%s\">%s</a></li>\n"}
      NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}
      {printf l, a[FNR],$0}' file1 file2
```

example:

```
kent$  seq -f"%g from file1" 7 >file1

kent$  seq -f"%g from file2" 7 >file2                                                                                                                                       

kent$  head file1 file2
==> file1 <==
1 from file1
2 from file1
3 from file1
4 from file1
5 from file1
6 from file1
7 from file1

==> file2 <==
1 from file2
2 from file2
3 from file2
4 from file2
5 from file2
6 from file2
7 from file2

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{l="<li><a href=\"%s\">%s</a></li>\n"};NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{printf l, a[FNR],$0}' file1 file2
<li><a href="1 from file1">1 from file2</a></li>
<li><a href="2 from file1">2 from file2</a></li>
<li><a href="3 from file1">3 from file2</a></li>
<li><a href="4 from file1">4 from file2</a></li>
<li><a href="5 from file1">5 from file2</a></li>
<li><a href="6 from file1">6 from file2</a></li>
<li><a href="7 from file1">7 from file2</a></li>
```

**EDIT**  for the comment of OP:

if you have only one file: (the `foo` here is just dummy text)

```
awk 'BEGIN{l="<li><a href=\"%s\">foo</a></li>\n"}{printf l,$0}' file1
```

output from same file1 example:

```
<li><a href="1 from file1">foo</a></li>
<li><a href="2 from file1">foo</a></li>
<li><a href="3 from file1">foo</a></li>
<li><a href="4 from file1">foo</a></li>
<li><a href="5 from file1">foo</a></li>
<li><a href="6 from file1">foo</a></li>
<li><a href="7 from file1">foo</a></li>
```

if you want to save the output to a file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{l="<li><a href=\"%s\">foo</a></li>\n"}{printf l,$0}' file1 > newfile
```

Comment: thanks that is awsome do u also have the code to do same but with one text file <a href="insert text here"> also how can i save the results to a text file

Comment: @DavidTuckwell see the EDIT in question

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
$ cat file1
aaaa
bbb
ccc

$ cat file2
111
222
333

$ paste file1 file2 | while read a b; do
    printf '<li><a href="file://%s">%s</a></li>\n' "$a" "$b"
done | tee newfile
```

### Output

```
<li><a href="file://aaaa">111</a></li>
<li><a href="file://bbb">222</a></li>
<li><a href="file://ccc">333</a></li>
```